# Mojarra 2.2.3 encoding request parameters

Tags: jsf, encoding, jboss, mojarra

**Problems started when I upgraded Mojarra from 2.2.1 to 2.2.3** (JBoss Wildfly Alpha to Beta).

When I try to submit a form (POST) with special characters (polish letters) they aren't properly UTF-8 encoded.

What I have done?

- Wrote a filter

  ```
  @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "ignore", value = "true" ), @WebInitParam(name = "encoding", value = "UTF-8") })
  public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

      private String encoding = null;
      private FilterConfig filterConfig;

      // Should a character encoding specified by client be ignored
      private boolean ignore = true;

      @Override
      public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
          this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
          this.encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
          String value = filterConfig.getInitParameter("ignore");

          this.ignore = ((value == null) || value.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || value.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
      }

      @Override
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

          if ((ignore || (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)) && (encoding != null)) {
              request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
              response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
          }

          chain.doFilter(request, response);
      }

      @Override
      public void destroy() {
          this.encoding = null;
          this.filterConfig = null;
      }
  }
  ```
- Every XHTML contains a line

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
- Layout also contains information about encoding

  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
- Added properties to standalone.xml

  ```
  <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
  <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
  <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  ```
- Logs in console when debugging request parameters from filter

  `index_form:people: Tischner PrzemysÅaw`

  `index_form:j_idt66:    index_form:j_idt66`

  `index_form:    index_form`

  `index_form:dbId:   2881850`

  `javax.faces.ViewState: 2748560203387116963:2575775533048879716`
- Request preview in browser 
  [image: Request in Chrome]
- How I initialize JSF page

  ```
  <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name="name" value="#{followNewView.name}" />
      <f:viewParam name="company" value="#{followNewView.company}" />
      <f:viewParam name="companyURL" value="#{followNewView.companyURL}" />
      <f:viewAction action="#{followNewView.init}" />
  </f:metadata>
  ```

Finally I'm still ending with improper encoding:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in Undertow encoding.

Solution here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2533

Answer (score 1):

here is a Bug about this:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2550

and here is one possible solution:

add this after your filter in web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CDI Conversation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

as described here:

http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/#3

Regards,

Martin

Comment: When I dumped the stack trace when parsing the request there was no trace of Weld packages. Everything was passed via Undertow.